# Making HTML friendly data from PHP echo

Tags: php, html, export-to-csv

I've been working with a PHP script to read a contact.csv file.  I would like to apply better styling to this table.  Is there a way to edit this script to make it more HTML friendly?

```
$row = 1;
if (($csvFile = fopen("contacts.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $i = 0;
    $wantedColumns = array(1,3,57);
    echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
    while (($data = fgetcsv($csvFile, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;
        echo "<tr>";
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) 
        {
            if (!in_array($c,$wantedColumns)) continue;
            echo "<td>$data[$c]</td>";
        }
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    fclose($csvFile);
}
```

I tried embedding this in html but the `echo "<td>$data[$c]</td>";` is throwing it off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concatenate all `html` content in one row and then `echo` it, otherwise it won't be valid as some tags require the closing `</>` tag with the opening one `<>` :

```
$html = "<table border='1' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'>";
while (($data = fgetcsv($csvFile, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    $row++;
    $html .= "<tr>";
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) 
    {
        if (!in_array($c,$wantedColumns)) continue;
        $html .= "<td>$data[$c]</td>";
    }
    $html .= "</tr>";
}
$html .= "</table>";
echo $html;
```

Comment: Is this meant to be run within a HTML file or PHP script?  I cannot get either to work.  Thanks for the fast response.

Comment: I don't get any display if I run straight PHP.

Comment: @Sethe23 : Is it possible that your loop is not running or conditions are skipped?

Comment: If I run it through an html file.  It looks like it escapes the last quotation mark here: `$html = "<table border=1 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0>"; 
`

Comment: @Sethe23 : there is a missing semicolon `;` on the 12 line

Comment: @Sethe23 : do you even debug your script?Look in the error_log to provide more information about your issue.

Comment: I didn't realize the code you provided left out `$row = 1;
if (($csvFile = fopen("contacts.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $i = 0;
    $wantedColumns = array(1,3,57);`  Thanks for your help.  If you can, please edit your code to include so no one makes the same mistake.